# Datepicker does not start with the <input> value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have this markup

```
 <input tabindex="5"  type="text" class="bgFecha date-pick" id="date2" value="12/03/2011" name="date2"/>
```

Please note the value of the input

but onclick the datepikcer starts with a 2 years later date:

[image]

This is the call:

```
$(function(){
    $('.date-pick').attr('readonly','true');
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true})
});
```

What is wrong? i need the datepicker to use the value="" date to start.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format for jquery datepicker it's `mm/dd/yy`. You need to use 12/03/11.

Or you can change the date [format](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-altFormat):

```
$(function(){
    $('.date-pick').attr('readonly','true');
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({ 
        clickInput:true, 
        altFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' // change the date format
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try set up date before you init the calendar like this

```
var today = new Date();
$('.date-pick').each(function(){
  $(this).val(today.toString("mm/dd/yy"));
});
```

Comment: That solution doesn't seem very clean. You should be able to make jquery bend to your will and not otherwise :)