# jquery datepicker input value format ignored

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is essentially the same as **[Datepicker does not start with the  value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997484/datepicker-does-not-start-with-the-input-value)** but that solution doesn't work.

My input is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="2012-05-01" class="hasDatepicker">
```

And my call is:

```
$("#start").datepicker({
    "dateFormat":"dd-mm-yy",
    "altFormat":"yy-mm-dd",
    "changeMonth":true,
    "changeYear":true
});
```

However, the altFormat is ignored and the date selected in the datepicker is always todays date.

I need the display date to be UK format of `dd-mm-yy` and the actual value SQL date as yy-mm-dd.

Which setting am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:-

```
$("#start").datepicker({     
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",     
    altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",     
    changeMonth:true,     
    changeYear:true 
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value using jQuery into `dd-mm-yy` format in doc ready like this

```
 $(function() {
    var parts = $('#start').val().split('-');
    $('#start').val(parts.reverse().join('-'))
    $("#start").datepicker({
       dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",     
       changeMonth:true,     
       changeYear:true              
   });
 });​
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/pJ6vN/)